# Get Ionic storage item as a string

Tags: angular, sqlite, typescript, ionic3, ionic-storage

As said in the title my problem is when I do:

```
this.storage.get('user')
```

I get this object

```
t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
```

and I don't know how to manipulate it.

I'm asking if there is a way to get a string value from my storage 
example

```js
// when i store user id like that 
this.storage.set("user", JSON.stringify(userID));
console.log(this.storage.get('user'))//output 100 for example
```

Comment: ionic storage returns a promise of the data..

Comment: thanks for that link now with some modification i'm able to get what i wanted from storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ionic storage returns a promise of the data. So, you have to wait for the promise to get resolved and get the data like below:

```
this.storage.get('user').then((result) => {
      console.log('My result', result);
});
```

Comment: it works for me like that, i have another question if possible
if i have some treatment  depending on that result all i have to do is to place it here ? `this.storage.get('user').then((result) => {
     // my code 
});`

Comment: If it works like that, then you can accept the answer. And can you please elaborate the second question?

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer certainly works.  Since follow-up comments are asking about how to use the resulting string from storage, an alternative is to use async/await to deal with the promises.  That can clean up the potential mess of nested `.then()`'s

```
let result: string = await this.storage.get('user');
//Use result here
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, is there a specific way to use this line of code like inside a method or something 
because when i use it directly like that it gives me this error
`Typescript Error Cannot find name 'await'.` 
and
`Typescript Error ',' expected. after await`

Comment: Typescript added support for `async/await` in 1.7.  An `await` needs to be inside a method marked with `async`.  See the typescript 1.7 docs for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html

Comment: thank you, i did it as u said and it works now i have a second question if you allow me of course,
is there a way to make a global variable and when ever i want to use the value i got from my storage all i have to do is using that variable?

Comment: Possible, yes.  You could make a property off an Angular service/provider, which gets populated (at startup?) from this async storage method.  The down side is the property will be null/empty until the async startup routine populates it.  Not much you can do there since getting things from storage is async and uses promises - you can't really force it into a simple variable.

Comment: hmmm thank you so the provider thing will be more for reducing line of codes and make it easier to manipulate